# First-Order logic exercise

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

Given this is true:

\begin{align} \neg \forall x \space \  \exists y \ ( x\neq y \rightarrow LeftOf(x,y) )\end{align}

Demonstrate :

\begin{align} \exists y \ \forall x (x = y \ \ \lor \ \ RightOf(y,x) ) \end{align}

With LeftOf and RightOf defined as: \begin{align}I(LeftOf) = {(x,y)} \\ I(RighftOf) = {(y,x)}\end{align}
I reach this point:
\begin{align} \exists y \ \exists x (x = y \ \ \lor \ \ RightOf(y,x) ) \end{align}
And I dont know how to translate this in what I'm required to.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the I notation
Is it true that `LeftOf(x,y) <--> ~LeftOf(y,x) <--> RightOf(y,x) <--> ~RightOf(x,y)` ?

Is this not the direct result of pushing the negation all the way in and then applying the above (And that `~x==y <--> x=/=y`)

Comment: Yes, the translations of LeftOf(x,y) you have written are all correct. I did what you suggested, but the problem I got is that it should be \begin{equation} \exists y \ \forall x\end{equation} and not  \begin{equation} \exists x \ \forall y\end{equation}.

Comment: I solved the problem, It was a silly mistake. Thanks for the help.